# Yii framework pass variable from controller to view

Tags: php, templates, yii, variable-assignment

To pass variable to login view I use:

```
$this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
```

But I also need acces this variable in template part footer.php:

I try this:

```
$this->render('footer', array('model' => $model));
```

But when in footer.php I try acces variable I get error "undefined variable"

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templates in yii are getting data from controller by `$this` reference.

```
<?php
SomeController extends Controller {
    public $something;

    public function init() {
        $this->something = 'qwerty';
    }
    public function actionA() {
        $this->render('view', array('model' => $model));
    }
}
```

In template:

```
<?php echo $this->something; ?>
```

Please take a look on default templates of yii. Breadcrimbs are displayed using property from controller, so this is propably the best way to achieve it.

Comment: $model variable not declare anywhere

Comment: I guess you haven't understand the question or the answer. The OP already had `$model` and asked how to pass it down to the view. This is not full controller code. Read the text again. PS. This is an accepted answer from 2014 - nobody complained about its correctness for almost 5 years. Maybe you are the one who does something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You can use controller class to pass variables in view template, for example

Controller :

```html
SomeController extends Controller {
    
    public function actionIndex() {
          $var1 = 'abc';
          $var2 = '123';
           $this->render('view', 
                           array('var1' => $var1,
                                 'var2' => $var2,
                                ));
    }
}
```

In view template file you can access these 2 variables ( $var1 & $var2) with its name :

```html
echo $var1; 

echo $var2
```

Answer (score 0):

mvc structure not redirect direct page.

you create first footer action and after redirect to page.

you see demo show login action in site_controller.php

follow this

Comment: login variable set in session

Comment: Noo, thisi s not solution