# Unable to transfer data to views

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii-components

To get a list of products, I created a model "ProductList"

```
namespace app\models;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class ProductList extends ActiveRecord{

      public static function tableName()
      {
            return 'product'; // Имя таблицы в БД
      }

}
```

Next, I created a controller to transfer data to views

```
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\ProductList;
use yii\web\Controller;
class SliderController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $product = ProductList::find()->all();
        return $this->render('index',compact('product'));
    }  
}
```

But checking in the index

```
<?php
    var_dump($product);
    die;
?>
```

I get NULL

Comment: Maybe `var_dump($this->product);`and `$this->product =... `? Just a guess. Do you maybe get a Notice in your logs as well ir you've enabled error reporting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii framework pass variable from controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993407/yii-framework-pass-variable-from-controller-to-view)  Best practice would be defined the public variable in the controller as well.

Comment: Did you try to var_dump `$product` variable in controller? To check if there is actually something returned by the `all()` method call. The fact that you are getting `NULL` and not "undefined variable" exception means, that the variable is passed to view but it's empty.

Comment: You get `NULL` if there are no rows that match your query. In your case, if the table is empty. Try `var_dump($product)`in the Controller before calling `$this->render(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller change actionIndex() method to :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $product = ProductList::find()->all();
    return $this->render('index',['productModel' => $product]);
}
```

And in view file first of all define your product variable and then use in list or gridviews, or whatever.

```
<?php

use app\models\ProductList;

/* @var $productModel ProductList */

var_dump($productModel);
?>
```

In view, I modified $product variable to $productModel so you will be more clear how that works.